# SSIS Data Transfer from Azure SQL to On-premises SQL Server 2016

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-2016, data-synchronization, azure-data-sync

Is there any way to transfer the large volume of data from Azure SQL to on-premises SQL Server 2016 Enterprise/Standard? The requirements prescribed as follows:

- Weekly full database transfer
- Daily delta transfer before midnight

I read about SSIS for Azure Blob Storage but am not sure whether it is applicable to this context.

Updated: I found an article on Azure Data Sync; according to that article, it seems doable. Please share your experiences. That would be extremely helpful.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3062/understanding-sql-data-sync-for-sql-server/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Weekly full database transfer

SSIS Doesn't provide a way to do Full transfer of data(i mean backup),unless you want to truncate  and insert from source..

For Weekly full database transfer,i would go with SQLAzure Export/Import functionality

Refer below links for more details..

1.https://github.com/richorama/SQLDatabaseBackup
2.[I need to automate SQL Azure database backup in SQL Script files. How can i do so?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8817246/i-need-to-automate-sql-azure-database-backup-in-sql-script-files-how-can-i-do-s)

> Daily delta transfer before midnight

You will need a way to identify delta..so create a table with all table names and last run time

create a console application which uses bulk insert functionality,which uses above table as base and insert in onpremises

Comment: try use Change Data Capture (CDC) with SSIS for daily delta transfer:  --
 (https://www.mattmasson.com/2011/12/cdc-in-ssis-for-sql-server-2012-2/)

-- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVF1JGFFt8w